# Get error when running Add-Migration in EF Core code-first

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, visual-studio-2022

I search internet a lot and ask question form chatgpt a lot, too, but I can't find my answer. I got error when I run `add-migration`:

> The property 'quizType' cannot be removed from entity type 'DataLayer.Models.QuizModel (Dictionary<string, object>)' because it is being used in the foreign key {'quizType'} on 'DataLayer.Models.QuizModel (Dictionary<string, object>)'. All containing foreign keys must be removed or redefined before the property can be removed.

But I don't removed anything I think the error is wrong this is my quiz context and my model:

```cs
namespace DataLayer.Models
{ 
    public class QuizType
    {
        [Key]
        [Required]
        public int quizType { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(150)]
        public string QuizTitle { get; set; }

        public QuizModel quizModel { get; set; }
    }
}
```

`UserModel`:

```cs
namespace DataLayer.Models
{
    public class UserModel
    {
        [Key]
        [Required]
        public int UserID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(300)]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(300)]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [AllowNull]
        [MaxLength(150)]
        public string Role { get; set; }

        public ICollection<QuizModel> quizes { get; set; }
    }
}
```

`QuizModel`:

```cs
namespace DataLayer.Models
{
    public class QuizModel
    {
        [Key]
        [Required]
        public int QuizID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(150)]
        public string QuizName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(300)]
        public string Categories { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int QuestionCount { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int QuizType { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("QuizType")]
        public QuizType quizType { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [ForeignKey("User")]
        public int UserID { get; set; }

        public UserModel User { get; set; }

        public ICollection<QuestionModel> Questions { get; set; }
    }
}
```

`QuestionModel`:

```cs
namespace DataLayer.Models
{
    public class QuestionModel
    {
        [Key]
        [Required]
        public int QuestionID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(400)]
        public string QuestionText { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int QuizType{ get; set; }

        [ForeignKey(name:"quiz")]
        public int QuizID { get; set; }

        public QuizModel quiz { get; set; } 

        public AnswerModel Answer { get; set; }

        public ICollection<AnswerOption> Oprtions { get; set; }
    }
}
```

`AnswerModel` and `AnswerOption` classes:

```cs
namespace DataLayer.Models
{
    public class AnswerModel
    {
        [Key]
        [Required]
        public int AnswerID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(300)]
        public string Answertxt { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [ForeignKey(name: "Question")]
        public int QuestionID { get; set; }

        public QuestionModel Question { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public bool AnswerValidation { get; set; }
    }

    public class AnswerOption
    {
        [Key]
        [Required]
        public int OptionID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(300)]
        public string Optiontxt { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public bool answerValidation { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [ForeignKey(name: "questionModel")]
        public int QuestionID { get; set; }

        public QuestionModel questionModel { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing wrong name for "QuizType" class Primary Key instead of just "quizType" you should do "QuizTypeID" or "ID" and this will resolve the issue.

Comment: Tnks my problem solved

Comment: But do you know what is my new problem that this erorr
Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Quizzes_QuizType_QuizTypeID' on table 'Quizzes' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

Comment: You need to revisit your all models and try to follow same name conventions like in same class you are starting properties with small latter and some starting with upper case this is causing confusion to read code for you and others as well.
Other you need to search and read about relations in code first approach. How we can create one-to-one, one-to-many and many-to-many relations in code classes. Yes you are right this issue is because to some circle  FOREIGN KEY constraints. Once you will be good for relations this will resolve the issue. Thanks!